# Can i read from ConcurrentHashmap with multiple threads simultaneously?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, hashmap, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

With one thread i haven't any problem when getting elements. But I want to get from ConcurrentHashmap with multiple threads simultaneously. If the map have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ; when i getting elements from ConcurrentHashMap with 2 threads i get 2,2,4,4,6,6,8,8. Can anybody help me?  İnside of every thread (Object of ReadFromBuffer class) i say

```
while(it.hasNext())
    {
        if(!it.hasNext()) continue;
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
         s=(String) pairs.getValue();.....
```

And multiple threads i get with (may be problem in this)

```
for(int i=1;i<=threadcount;i++)
      {   
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ReadFromBuffer(map),"" );
        t2.start();
      }
```

Can anybody tell me how read ConcurrentHashmap with multiple threads simultaneosly with example ?

Comment: What result were you expecting to get?  Reading from a hashmap (concurrent or otherwise) does not remove the value that was read.  It sounds like you want a Queue (probably a ConcurrentQueue)

Comment: I need that if i read some value from Buffer(or Queue with other words) i remove it because i dont want next thread read it second time. Completly scene is that: One thread writing to buffer and many threads reading it concurrently.

Comment: @Juniorjava: your comment makes no sense. You explain that you don’t use a Queue because you want exactly what a Queue does.

Comment: I solved my problem with BlockedQueue. Thank you all for idea using Queue.